# UIDate Picker formate issue in changing region

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uidatepicker

i am creating date picker like this:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[datePicker setFrame:self.txtFieldDatePicker.frame];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setLocale:[self getCurrentLocale]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

NSDate *dateForPicker = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.txtFieldDatePicker.text];
if (dateForPicker)
{
    [datePicker setDate:dateForPicker];
}
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

objc_setAssociatedObject(datePicker,
                         (void*)MyConstKeyForDatePicker,
                         self.txtFieldDatePicker,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
//                datePicker.tag = txtField.tag+1;
self.txtFieldDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;

self.txtFieldDatePicker.inputView = datePicker;
```

my getCurrentLocal:

```
-(NSLocale *)getCurrentLocale
{
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale;
enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
return enUSPOSIXLocale;
}
```

i am expecting UIDatePicker to always show daye in MM-dd-yyyy.

**Interesting:
when i go to iPad setting > general > and change region to United States, my code works perfectly that is always UIDatePicker shows in MM-dd-yyyy.If i change region to any thing else (India), UIdate Picker shows date in dd-MM-yyyy why?**

i always want to show in MM-dd-yyyy.

Thanks

Comment: did you try not to set the locale on the NSDateFormatter?

Comment: after commenting out getCurrentLocale nothing change, the behaviour remain same as i described in my question.i will remove getCurrentLocale from my code (depending on answers i will get).

Comment: I think you need to set the locale of the datePicker, as well as the date formatter.

Comment: please remind me... why is it a problem to show the format of the date/time in accordance with the _end-user_ wishes? exactly this is the kind of aggression why I'd delete an application and find and alternative one.

Comment: i am 100% agree with @holex , and been able to convince my client.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 NSLocale *indain = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"];
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setLocale:indain];
    [datePicker setCalendar:cal];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```